# 3D Graphing Package For C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d

I'm using ZedGraph for my 2D graphing needs, but for a project, I need something that does 3d graphing.  What is the best package I can use for this?  I'd like the Graph Panes to be as easy to manipulate as with ZedGraph.

Edit: By 3D, I mean I want to be able to specify an x,y,z to get a surface.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using nevron chart for winforms and it has the [surface](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-chart-gallery-charting-types-grid-surface-chart.aspx) you're looking for, so it will meet your requirements. Plus, you can customize anything on it.

Comment: Oops sorry, I just realized this is a 4 years old post, but hopefully my comment could be of help to people who are still interested in the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the source code that can be found in the link posted just below as well as WPF you can create a pretty good 3d graph, it's nothing groundbreaking but it might suit your needs:

[3D Bar Chart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_3D_Bar_chart_control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can create a bitmap using [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) and display it. MathGL is cross-platform GPL (LGPL for core) plotting library which can plot 2- and 3-ranged data. However, I'm not sure what you can use C++ classes from C#. But C-interface should work.